# Which one is better jquery mobile or phonegap

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

Hi guys i am going to make a android game. i wanna know that which one is better for beginner on android like me. i know js. kindly suggest me that which one i have to use **phonegap** or **jquery mobile**?
Regards

Comment: "Which is better, a computer or a piece of bacon?"

Comment: You asked this question before even reading the websites for the two frameworks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

they are two very different things. Phonegap is a bridge between native and HTML, CSS and JS. jQuery mobile is a framework / library that can be used within phonegap.

Phonegap will take your jQuery mobile application and allow you to run it like a native app, where jQuery mobile alone will just run online in a browser.

Comment: thanks...any tutorials related to phone gap that will help me ?

Comment: Honestly phonegap is pretty easy to pick up, develop your game in a browser get things working, once you've got things rocking in browser you can take that code and create a new phonegap project in eclipse and put your HTML,CSS and JS into it and you can then access native systems. Check out the google group for phonegap lots of smart people and answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use Jquery mobile independently.But u can use phonegap without jquery mobile.

You can use other frameworks like sencha touch,Launchair,XUI,Glove box etc with phonegap.
These are the development tools by using which u can develop mobile app within phonegap.